# Using a function to make a dict won't work, but outside the function does

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, fasta

I have a problem that I can't seem to find and fix.

```
FASTA = >header1
         ATCGATCGATCCCGATCGACATCAGCATCGACTAC
         ATCGACTCAAGCATCAGCTACGACTCGACTGACTACGACTCGCT
        >header2
         ATCGATCGCATCGACTACGACTACGACTACGCTTCGTATCAGCATCAGCT
         ATCAGCATCGACGACGACTAGCACTACGACTACGACGATCCCGATCGATCAGCT

def dnaSequence():
    '''
    This function makes a dict called DNAseq by reading the fasta file 
    given as first argument on the command line
    INPUT: Fasta file containing strings
    OUTPUT: key is header and value is sequence
    '''

    DNAseq = {}
    for line in FASTA:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith('>'):
            header = line
            DNAseq[header] = ""
        else:
            seq = line
            DNAseq[header] = seq

    return DNAseq



def digestFragmentsWithOneEnzyme(dnaSequence):
    '''
    This function digests the sequence from DNAseq into smaller parts
    by using the enzymes listed in the MODES.
    INPUT: DNAseq and the enzymes from sys.argv[2:]
    OUTPUT: The DNAseq is updated with the segments gained from the
    digesting
    '''
    enzymes = sys.argv[2:]

    updated_list = []
    for enzyme in enzymes:
        pattern = MODES(enzyme)
        p = re.compile(pattern)
        for dna in DNAseq.keys():
            matchlist = re.findall(p,dna)
            updated_list = re.split(MODES, DNAseq)
            DNAseq.update((key, updated_list.index(k)) for key in
            d.iterkeys())
    return DNAseq


def getMolecularWeight(dnaSequence):
    '''
    This function calculates the molWeight of the sequence in DNAseq
    INPUT: the updated DNAseq from the previous function as a dict
    OUTPUT: The DNAseq is updated with the molweight of the digested fragments
    '''

    results = []
    for seq in DNAseq.keys():
        results = sum((dnaMass[base]) for base in DNAseq[seq])
        DNAseq.update((key, results.index(k)) for key in
        d.iterkeys())
    return DNAseq


def main(argv=None):
    '''
    This function prints the results of the digested DNA sequence on in the terminal.
    INPUT: The DNAseq from the previous function as a dict
    OUTPUT: name     weight weight weight
            name2    weight weight weight
    '''
    if argv == None:
        argv = sys.argv
    if len(argv) <2:
        usage()
        return 1

    digestFragmentsWithOneEnzyme(dnaSequence())
    Genes = getMolecularWeight(digestFragmentsWithOneEnzyme())
    print ({header},{seq}).format(**DNAseq)
    return 0



if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

In the first function I'm trying to make a `dict` from the fasta file, using the same `dict` in the second function where the sequences are being sliced by regex and finally the `molweight` is being calculated.

My problem is that for some reason Python doesn't recognize my `dict` and I get an error:

> name error DNAseq is not defined

If I make the `dict` outside of the function then I do have the `dict`.

Comment: Please fix your code block.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the dict to both functions as `dnaSequence`, not `DNAseq`.

Note this is a very strange way of calling functions. You completely ignore the result of the first call to `digestFragmentsWithOneEnzyme` when you pass the sequence to it, then try to call it again to pass the result to `getMolecularWeight` but you fail to actually pass the sequence in that call, so that would actually error if you got that far.

I *think* what you are trying to do is this:

```
sequence = dnaSequence()
fragments = digestFragmentsWithOneEnzyme(sequence)
genes = getMolecularWeight(fragments)
```

and you should avoid calling the parameter to both functions with the same name as a separate function, as that will hide the function name. Instead, choose a new name:

```
def digestFragmentsWithOneEnzyme(sequence):
    ...
    for dna in sequence:
```

(you don't need to call `keys()` - iterating over a dict is always over the keys.)